# Copying an attribute to a variable, attribute gets changed instead

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save a list of dictionaries as a JSON file. The list has datetime objects which need to be converted, so I pass the list to a `json_data` variable, change the datetime into strings, and save that instead.

Here is my code to add a new dictionary entry and save it:

```
TODAY = datetime.date.today()

    class Deck():

        def __init__(self):
            self.cards = []

        def add(self, question, answer):
            '''Create a new card'''
            card = {
                'question': question,
                'answer': answer,
                'date_added': TODAY,
                'review_date': TODAY,
                }
            self.cards.append(card)

        def save(self):
            '''Save cards'''
            json_data = []
            for card in self.cards:
                json_data.append(card)

            for data in json_data:
                data['date_added'] = data['date_added'].isoformat()
                data['review_date'] = data['review_date'].isoformat()

            with open('cards.json', 'w') as obj:
                json.dump(json_data, obj)
```

The file saves alright, but for some reason `self.cards` is getting changed instead of `json_data`. I want the datetime objects in self.cards to stay that way. Say the instance is called `deck`:

```
>>> deck.add('1 + 1',2)
>>> deck.cards[0]['date_added']
datetime.date(2017, 2, 12)
>>> deck.save()
>>> deck.cards[0]['date_added']
'2017-02-12'
>>> deck.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
data['date_added'] = data['date_added'].isoformat()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isoformat'
```

Not sure why this is happening, I did a few searches but could not find a solution. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The error does not match the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save your data, you need to make a copy of each card. Otherwise, when you convert the dates, you'll still be modifying the original cards.

So try this instead:

```
    def save(self):
        '''Save cards'''
        json_data = []
        for card in self.cards:
            card = card.copy()
            card['date_added'] = card['date_added'].isoformat()
            card['review_date'] = card['review_date'].isoformat()
            json_data.append(card)

        with open('cards.json', 'w') as obj:
            json.dump(json_data, obj)
```